# Time Machine/Time Capsule: What is the difference between "Waiting for index to be ready (100)" and "Waiting for index to be ready (101)"?

Tags: macos, time-machine, backup, time-capsule, indexing

What's the difference between these (100) and (101) indexing processes?

Having finally created a successful backup to Time Capsule using Time Machine under Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5 (11G63), I'm still experiencing longer than expected indexing wait times. These are recorded in Console ("backupd") as "Waiting for index to be ready (100)" and "Waiting for index to be ready (101)."  While the process/function is being performed, a related entry is recorded in Console every minute (example follows).

My curiosity is specific: what is the difference between "101" and "100"?

```
10/8/12 7:33:24.150 AM com.apple.backupd: Waiting for index to be ready (101)
10/8/12 7:34:24.359 AM com.apple.backupd: Waiting for index to be ready (101)
10/8/12 7:35:24.553 AM com.apple.backupd: Waiting for index to be ready (101)
10/8/12 7:36:24.621 AM com.apple.backupd: Waiting for index to be ready (101)
10/8/12 7:37:24.697 AM com.apple.backupd: Waiting for index to be ready (101)
10/8/12 7:38:25.169 AM com.apple.backupd: Waiting for index to be ready (101)
10/8/12 7:39:25.351 AM com.apple.backupd: Waiting for index to be ready (100)
10/8/12 7:40:25.723 AM com.apple.backupd: Waiting for index to be ready (100)
10/8/12 7:41:26.031 AM com.apple.backupd: Waiting for index to be ready (100)
10/8/12 7:42:26.200 AM com.apple.backupd: Waiting for index to be ready (100)
10/8/12 7:43:26.244 AM com.apple.backupd: Waiting for index to be ready (100)
10/8/12 7:44:26.357 AM com.apple.backupd: Waiting for index to be ready (100)
10/8/12 7:45:26.462 AM com.apple.backupd: Waiting for index to be ready (100)
10/8/12 7:46:26.618 AM com.apple.backupd: Waiting for index to be ready (100)
10/8/12 7:47:26.664 AM com.apple.backupd: Waiting for index to be ready (100)
10/8/12 7:48:26.851 AM com.apple.backupd: Waiting for index to be ready (100)
10/8/12 7:49:26.974 AM com.apple.backupd: Waiting for index to be ready (100)
10/8/12 7:50:27.185 AM com.apple.backupd: Waiting for index to be ready (100)
10/8/12 7:51:27.338 AM com.apple.backupd: Waiting for index to be ready (100)
10/8/12 7:52:27.516 AM com.apple.backupd: Waiting for index to be ready (100)
10/8/12 7:53:27.715 AM com.apple.backupd: Waiting for index to be ready (100)
```

Comment: Hi I am just trawling old questions and am wondering if you solved this, or if you looked at http://pondini.org/TM/D2.html this covers your problem specifically, however does not answer your question about 100 v 101 messages.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is that the difference between these two codes (100 and 101) is not publicly documented by apple.

https://discussions.apple.com/message/23429422?ac_cid=op123456#23429422

However [pondini.org/TM/D2.html](http://pondini.org/TM/D2.html) gives reasons why and how to fix those errors, and the issues you are experiencing.

Comment: Hi Deesbeck, Apple support was able to solve much of the issue, but even the techs there were never able to learn the difference between "100" and "101." Thank you for your interest.